# Upload file using org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPSClient

Tags: java, ftps

I am working on File Upload using Java API.
I want to upload file into server by using FTPS , I found that I can use Google library of apache commons net but I am facing issue in `org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPSClient` when i upload file. 
Following is the error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

this is my code :

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
            String server = "HOST";
            int port = 21;
            String user = "USER";
            String pass = "PASS";

            FTPSClient ftpClient;
            try {
                ftpClient = new FTPSClient();

            try {

                ftpClient.connect(server, port);
                ftpClient.login(user, pass);
                ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();

                ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);

                // APPROACH #1: uploads first file using an InputStream
                File firstLocalFile = new File("TEST1.CSV");

                String firstRemoteFile = "TEST1.txt";
                InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(firstLocalFile);

                System.out.println("Start uploading first file");

                boolean done = ftpClient.storeFile(firstRemoteFile, inputStream);
                inputStream.close();
                if (done) {
                    System.out.println("The first file is uploaded successfully.");
                }

                // APPROACH #2: uploads second file using an OutputStream
                File secondLocalFile = new File("TEST2.CSV");
                String secondRemoteFile = "TEST2.TXT";
                inputStream = new FileInputStream(secondLocalFile);

                System.out.println("Start uploading second file");
                OutputStream outputStream = ftpClient.storeFileStream(secondRemoteFile);
                byte[] bytesIn = new byte[4096];
                int read = 0;

                while ((read = inputStream.read(bytesIn)) != -1) {
                    outputStream.write(bytesIn, 0, read);
                }
                inputStream.close();
                //outputStream.close();

                boolean completed = ftpClient.completePendingCommand();
                if (completed) {
                    System.out.println("The second file is uploaded successfully.");
                }

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
                ex.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (ftpClient.isConnected()) {
                        ftpClient.logout();
                        ftpClient.disconnect();
                    }
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Any support is appreciated

Comment: Which of these two approaches causes the error?

Comment: An Exception is nice, however the stracktrace (and the line number where the exception in your code occurred) would be more useful. Could you please edit your question and add both?